# Dynamic Import Scoped SCSS

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I have a VueJS project that has a base component that can be styled differently depending n server config. Right now I am loading CSS from the server but I was wondering if it is possible to import scoped scss in vuejs dynamically. i.e

```
<style src="{{style_name_or_path}}" lang="scss" scoped/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to load dynamic styles that way. I'd suggest you to use [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) to handle different styles.